# Description of Office 365 Page Templates

Tags: public-website, office-365

The Office 365 public site (plan E3) offers a number of standard page templates: About Us, Comparison Grid, etc.

Where can I find a description of these templates? I mean something more detailed than what SharePoint displays in the Create interface.

Comment: I'd love to see some explanation on this subject as well.